# Segmentation fault in binary search tree while searching for minimum

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault

So I'm learning data structures in C and binary search tree is giving me a hard time, i have run gdb to see in which line the seg fault is and its in line 77(marked in code). I just don't seem to understand as why this is happening, here is my code and thanks in advance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>


typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right; 
} node;
node* getNewNode();
node* insert();
bool searchTree();  
int getMin();


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random;
    node* root;
    int var;
    printf("Genereting tree with random values...\n");//Adding random numbers
    for(int i=1;i<15;i++){
        random = rand();
        insert(root, random);
        printf("%d\n", random);
    }
    printf("Last value added: %d\n", random);

    /*
    printf("Enter number to search: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &var);
    printf("%s\n", searchTree(root, var) ? "true": "false");
    */
    printf("min: %d\n", getMin(root)); //Printing min value

    return 0;
}
node* getNewNode(int data){
    node* newNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
node* insert(node* root, int data){

    if(root == NULL){
        root = getNewNode(data);
        return root;
    }
    else if(data <= root->data){
        root->left = insert(root->left, data);
    }
    else{
        root->right = insert(root->right, data);
    }
    return root;
    }
bool searchTree(node* root, int data){

    if(root == NULL)
        return false;

    else if(root-> data == data)
        return true;

    else if(data <= root->data)
        return searchTree(root->left, data);
    else
        return searchTree(root->right, data);
}

int getMin(node* root){
    if(root->left == NULL){     //Here is where the error is
        return root->data;
    }

    return getMin(root->left);


}
```

Comment: Is root itself null? (Just a guess)

Comment: Please read and follow the advice in "[How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".  You may also find [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) helpful; it is very likely that the _bug_ is not on the line where the _crash_ happens.

Comment: Please also realize that with a program like this, that takes input, you need to tell us _exactly_ what you typed at it before it crashed, or we may not be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please explain where the value of `root` is initialized in your code

Comment: 1) `node* root;` --> `node* root = NULL;` 2) `insert(root, random);` --> `root = insert(root, random);`

Comment: ok, so root is created in first if statement in method insert() if it already does not exist, as for what i typed at it i dont understand since for loop in main is generating tree for me so there is not any input from my side. commented code in main() is for searching if value exists in a tree and returns boolean(it works)

Comment: _root is created in first if statement in method insert() if it already does not exist_ — Yes, but you have `node* root;`, so root _doesn't_ not exist, it is _uninitialized_.  You probably meant to write `node *root = 0;`.  (N.B. unary star binds to the _right_ and should be cuddled accordingly.)  I'm sure this is not the only bug though.

Comment: @zwol Why does my search function that takes that same root pointer as an argument work properly?

Comment: If any code that uses uninitialized local variables appears to work, it is only by accident, and there is a latent bug waiting to happen — with a different compiler, or if the runtime environment changes even a little.

Answer (score 0):

> You are getting segmentation fault because you are not assigning root
>   the address of root of tree in main

```
node* root=0;
    for(int i=1;i<15;i++){
        random = rand();
        root=insert(root, random);//assigning root the starting address of root of tree
        printf("%d\n", random);
    }
```

Comment: If you just dump the correct code on someone this confused, they don't learn anything.  Don't do that.  Also, you do not appear to have fixed _all_ of the bugs.  Only dump correct code if you have fixed _all_ of the bugs and you have _verified_ by testing that this is so.

Comment: But sir i put the comment where i modified the code

Comment: does it is write@zwol

Comment: Yes, but they're not going to notice.  Also, again, you didn't fix _all_ of the bugs.  (Your revised answer is better but is still not actually all that helpful.)

Comment: but i only modified this thing and it is working fine

Comment: I really appreciate any help i can get so thank you. How come my search function works even without  writing root=...? I thought root is a pointer accessible in main() and it stores address of a tree

Comment: @MohitYadav If you didn't change `node* root;` to `node *root = 0;` then it is only working for you by accident; and I will be very surprised if there are only two bugs.  (You *are* correct to say that throwing away the value returned by `insert` is a bug.)

Comment: Why does my search function that takes root pointer as an argument work properly?